# Azure RSA HSM signing - bad chars in base64

Tags: php, azure, ssl, rsa, hsm

We are trying to use Azure HSM for digital signatures. Unfortunately, there are differences between what we have from PHP and from HSM.

I.e. the same content signed from PHP with openssl_sign methods returns

```
string(344) "SgPUHc0bKz9d6KetdnNZxIguqDmrj9+B9kQO0t3mxObZ2+EndJ0MEDIuYEcj20BaIlXuM+IAFz25jeZy7VnoGsq+r/L3nxi4b+C6HE7Nw1EyQ3Hz5Tm53bdjr0w25LDOvRFxnxqrzzkxo2K66/Lm0DHMs1r/7XcQhpYEKhZsMCwnk4KzPt3YdE/WpdO+yyVoaM19l+4vVu/GMOKLbQhTtNPEZ+2dw4YtIiUmJz/9o/ARdTaI8XMFWQxQCEgdnii+I1TuuQVKa2BQPPAPNYjJJFU2H9UzxXj1dKxHinCnW8jNZ57gf41PEypqtf8ebFSunWyxdtWdIQ+RjRoJoQLTxQ=="
```

Content signed by Azure HSM looks like this

```
string(342) "SgPUHc0bKz9d6KetdnNZxIguqDmrj9-B9kQO0t3mxObZ2-EndJ0MEDIuYEcj20BaIlXuM-IAFz25jeZy7VnoGsq-r_L3nxi4b-C6HE7Nw1EyQ3Hz5Tm53bdjr0w25LDOvRFxnxqrzzkxo2K66_Lm0DHMs1r_7XcQhpYEKhZsMCwnk4KzPt3YdE_WpdO-yyVoaM19l-4vVu_GMOKLbQhTtNPEZ-2dw4YtIiUmJz_9o_ARdTaI8XMFWQxQCEgdnii-I1TuuQVKa2BQPPAPNYjJJFU2H9UzxXj1dKxHinCnW8jNZ57gf41PEypqtf8ebFSunWyxdtWdIQ-RjRoJoQLTxQ"
```

There are just few differences:
instead of `+` char Azure HSM returns `-`
instead of `/` char Azure HSM returns `_`
and signature from Azure is not padded.

These characters are not allowed by base 64: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table

Does anyone have an idea from where these differences may come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea from where these differences may came from?

Azure appears to use URL safe base64, as specific in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5). You can find it in the [“Variants summary table” section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) you linked.

Comment: Thank you very much. RFC 4648 was the right keywords here.